# Kendo UI dataSource changed event: is it working?

Tags: events, kendo-ui, grid, datasource

Is the dataSource.changed event working?

After my Kendo UI grid is instantiated, I am binding the change event per the documentation here:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#change

```js
//To set after initialization
dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
    // handle event
});
```

I am doing this:

```js
// initialize
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource, 

        blah blah blah
)

});
// end of initialization



// bind afterwards
 var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
  grid.dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
      dataChanged();
  });


 //also tried a setTimeout:

  // bind afterwards
  setTimeout(function () {
    var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
        dataChanged();
    });
}, 350);



 function dataChanged() {
   // handle "change" whatever that means -- documentation definition is hazy
   // does reassigning the data array constitute a change?
   // does changing the value of a particular item in the data array
   // constitute a change?
   // does removing an item from the data array constitute a change?

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.refresh();
 }
```

But my dataChanged() function is not called when I do either of these things:

```js
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.dataSource.data()[1]["deptname"] = 'XXX';
```

or

```js
grid.dataSource.data = aDifferentArray;
```

I am not sure exactly what the 'changed' event is listening for. What, precisely, is supposed to trigger it?

If I create a completely new dataSource, and assign it to the grid that already has a dataSource, I don't see how that would trigger an existing data source's changed event.  Such an event (the grid noticing that its dataSource has been replaced with a different one) would be a grid-level event, not a dataSource-level event, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important thing to note is that the data backing the `DataSource` is an `ObservableArray`, and that the data items in that array are converted to `ObservableObject`s.

The `change` event of the datasource is fired under 2 conditions:

1. The data `ObservableArray` changes (a record is inserted, deleted). An example of this would be using the `DataSource.add()` or `DataSource.remove()` functions.
2. If a property changed event bubbles up to the DataSource from one of the `ObservableData` objects in the array. However, just like the rest of the Kendo MVVM framework, the notification that a property changed only occurs when its `.set("propertyName", value)` function is called.

This is why `grid.dataSource.data()[1]["deptname"] = 'XXX';` is not triggering the change event. If you change it to: `grid.dataSource.data()[1].set("deptname", 'XXX');` then it should start to work. Basically, think of the `change` event as being fired in response to an MVVM property change fired from the `data` observable object.

As for changing the data array `grid.dataSource.data = aDifferentArray;` I'm actually not sure if that will or should trigger a change. I've never tried that.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  The `.set` method does trigger the change event whereas `grid.dataSource.data = aDifferentArray` does not, as far as I can tell. I hope there is in Kendo grid an equivalent to DataSource_Changed event in WinForms grids--fired when the grid is assigned a different datasource, because I am hoping to refresh the grid with new data every 60 seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892021/kendo-ui-grid-refreshing-grid-data-every-60-seconds-with-new-data-datasource-a/13892541#comment19140263_13892541

Comment: Actually, to swap out the data, I think you use the `.data()` function: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data so your code would be `grid.dataSource.data(aDifferentArray);`

Comment: has anyone considered using kendo.Observable? i'm trying to put my datasource as an observable so whenever there's a change it will update the view model