# Kendo UI: bug with observe pattern in dataSource when grouping

Tags: datasource, kendo-ui

I assign the grid a dataSource at configuration time:

```
parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: parsedData
    });



$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        etc etc
        .
        .
        .
```

Then I bind to the change event post-configuration/initialization:

```
    var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
        dataChanged();
    });

function dataChanged() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.refresh();
}
```

Then I remove all of the items in the data array of the dataSource:

```
 while (grid.dataSource.data().length > 0) {
    grid.dataSource.data().pop();
}
```

The rows in the grid disappear, as anticipated. But then, with the empty grid, I drag a column header to the group panel, the grid repopulates itself.

I am trying to find a way to refresh the grid's data every 60 seconds, so it's important for me to know how to clear the data and replace it with different data, without having vestigial data somewhere that isn't tuned in to the observed array of observed objects.

Or maybe I am doing something wrong or incompletely -- very possible, since I'm just beginning to work with Kendo UI.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892021/kendo-ui-grid-refreshing-grid-data-every-60-seconds-with-new-data-datasource-a) question you need to use the [data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data) method of the data source.

Comment: Although for the 60-second refresh I will replace the data array in its entirety using the data() method of the dataSource, in other scenarios I will need to remove individual rows from the data array. Why are those removed rows "recreated" so to speak by dragging the column header to the grouping panel?  Is there a vestigial copy of the dataset referenced by the grouping algorithms, as though they had not been informed by the observer that the rows had been removed from the data array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try creating a demo in jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com.